# Spark on yarn jar upload problems

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am trying to run a simple Map/Reduce java program using spark over yarn (Cloudera Hadoop 5.2 on CentOS). I have tried this 2 different ways. The first way is the following:

```
YARN_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/; 
/var/tmp/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class MRContainer --master yarn-cluster --jars /var/tmp/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar  simplemr.jar
```

This method gives the following error:

> diagnostics: Application application_1434177111261_0007 failed 2 times
>   due to AM Container for appattempt_1434177111261_0007_000002 exited
>   with  exitCode: -1000 due to: Resource
>   hdfs://kc1ltcld29:9000/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1434177111261_0007/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
>   changed on src filesystem (expected 1434549639128, was 1434549642191

Then I tried without the --jars:

```
YARN_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/; 
/var/tmp/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class MRContainer --master yarn-cluster simplemr.jar
```

> diagnostics: Application application_1434177111261_0008 failed 2 times
>   due to AM Container for appattempt_1434177111261_0008_000002 exited
>   with  exitCode: -1000 due to: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://kc1ltcld29:9000/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1434177111261_0008/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
>   .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
>            ApplicationMaster host: N/A
>            ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
>            queue: root.myuser
>            start time: 1434549879649
>            final status: FAILED
>            tracking URL: http://kc1ltcld29:8088/cluster/app/application_1434177111261_0008
>            user: myuser Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application
>   application_1434177111261_0008 finished with failed status
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:841)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:867)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 15/06/17 10:04:57 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called 15/06/17
>   10:04:57 INFO util.Utils: Deleting directory
>   /tmp/spark-2aca3f35-abf1-4e21-a10e-4778a039d0f4

I tried deleting all the .jars from hdfs://users//.sparkStaging and resubmitting but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by copying spark-assembly.jar into a directory on the hdfs for each node and then passing it to spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.jar as a parameter. Commands are listed below:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /var/tmp/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar /user/spark/spark-assembly.jar 

/var/tmp/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class MRContainer --master yarn-cluster  --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs:///user/spark/spark-assembly.jar simplemr.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error it means you are uploading assembly jars using `--jars` option or manually copying to hdfs in each node.
I have followed this approach and it works for me.

In yarn-cluster mode, Spark submit **automatically uploads the assembly jar to a distributed cache that all executor containers** read from, so there is no need to manually copy the assembly jar to all nodes (or pass it through `--jars`).
It seems there are two versions of the same jar in your HDFS.

Try removing all old jars from your .sparkStaging directory and try again, it should work.