# Overwrite Spark version in depencency

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies

In [this presentation](https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Productionizing-a-247-Spark-Streaming-Service-on-YARN-Ooyala.pdf) they show an example of "upgrading" Spark version just by passing newer spark-assembly.jar as a dependency. Here's relevant snippet ("upgrading" from Spark 0.9 to 1.1):

```
export SPARK_JAR=/usr/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.2.0.jar
java -cp /etc/hadoop/conf:AppJar.jar:spark-assembly.jar org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client --jar AppJar.jar --addJars /jars/config.jar --class ooyala.app.MainClass --arg arg1 --arg arg2 --name MyApp
```

This is very nice possibility since it allows to use **latest features** without the need to **upgrade the whole cluster** very often. However, code above is totally outdated now, so I tried to use something similar with `spark-submit` (trying to add jar of Spark 1.5 to a cluster running Spark 1.2):

```
~/spark-1.5/bin/spark-submit \
   --jars ~/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar \
   --class ooyala.app.MainClass 
   --master yarn-client 
   ooyala-test_2.10-1.0.jar
```

But it doesn't work either, resulting in `NullPointerException` deep in Spark internals.

Does anyone have experience doing this trick on recent versions of Spark?

Comment: Maybe you also need to configure spark.yarn.jar and hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893995/spark-on-yarn-jar-upload-problems/30925128#30925128 and http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Configure+MapR+Client+Node++to+Run+Spark+Applications